MEF throws System.InvalidOperationException: 'AtomicComposition encountered an unexpected Exception with disposable types
I have a problem using C# and MEF when combining different types which partially are created and administrated by a MEF CompositionContainer and partially are administrated by my code and online added/removed by CompositionBatches.
I tried to reduce it to an easy test and my classes look like this:
[Export]
    [PartNotDiscoverable]
    public class Module : IDisposable, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
    {
        private Admin? _admin;

        public Module()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Create Module");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dispose Module");
        }

        public void OnImportsSatisfied()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Module satisfied");
        }

        [Import(AllowDefault = true, AllowRecomposition = true)]
        public Admin? Admin
        {
            get { return _admin; }
            set
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Set Module Admin {value?.MyCounter}");
                _admin = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [Export]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class Admin : IDisposable, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
    {
        public Admin()
        {
            MyCounter = ++_counter;
            Console.WriteLine($"Create Admin {MyCounter}");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Dispose Admin {MyCounter}");
        }

        public void OnImportsSatisfied()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Admin {MyCounter} satisfied");
        }

        [Import(AllowDefault = true, AllowRecomposition = true)]
        public Module? Module
        {
            get { return _module; }
            set
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Set Admin {MyCounter} module {value} setter");
                _module = value;
            }
        }

        public int MyCounter;

        private static int _counter;
        private Module? _module;
    }

You can ignore the implementation of IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification. I just tried to figure out what MEF is doing so remove it if you want (it doesn't effect the outcome).
The code that uses those two classes look like this:
    public class Logic
    {
        public Logic()
        {
            var typeCatalog = new TypeCatalog(typeof(Module), typeof(Admin));
            Container = new CompositionContainer(typeCatalog, CompositionOptions.DisableSilentRejection | CompositionOptions.IsThreadSafe);
        }

        public CompositionContainer Container { get; set; }

        public void Do()
        {
            var mod1 = new Module();

            var batch = new CompositionBatch();
            var composablePart = batch.AddPart(mod1);
            Container.Compose(batch);

            Console.WriteLine("Delete from container");

            batch = new CompositionBatch();
            batch.RemovePart(composablePart);
            Container.Compose(batch);
        }
    }

I realize that the instances of Module and Admin are internally administrated differently by the CompositionContainer because one of them is given by a CompositionBatch and the other is created by the container itself.
My problem is that the last 'Compose(batch)' statement throws an exception:
*
System.InvalidOperationException: AtomicComposition encountered an unexpected Exception, review InnerException for details.
---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.DisposableReflectionComposablePart'.) (Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.DisposableReflectionComposablePart'.)
---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.DisposableReflectionComposablePart'.
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.DisposableReflectionComposablePart.EnsureRunning()
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ReflectionComposablePart.RequiresRunning()
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ReflectionComposablePart.SetImport(ImportDefinition definition, IEnumerable`1 exports)
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.PartManager.TrySetImport(ImportDefinition import, Export[] exports)
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.b__0()
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AtomicComposition.FinalComplete()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #1) System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.DisposableReflectionComposablePart'.
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.DisposableReflectionComposablePart.EnsureRunning()
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ReflectionComposablePart.RequiresRunning()
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ReflectionComposablePart.Activate()
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.PartManager.TryOnComposed()
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.b__0()
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AtomicComposition.FinalComplete()<---
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AtomicComposition.FinalComplete()
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AtomicComposition.Complete()
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ComposablePartExportProvider.Compose(CompositionBatch batch)
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.Compose(CompositionBatch batch)
at MEFMultiContainer.Logic.Do() in C:\Users\tne\source\repos\MEFMultiContainer\MEFMultiContainer\Program.cs:line 39*
I don't understand why the container is trying to recompose the already - by himself - disposed instance of Admin.
My expectation was that the last batch would remove the Module from the container and disposes the Admin without any exceptions.
I realize I can solve my problem by giving Admin a CreationPolicy.Shared. But I would like to understand why I get this exceptions.
So thanks for any help!
